# Найти кратчайший путь

Tags: c++, c

знаю таких программ куча и т.д., но найти подходящую я не смог. Может у кого имеется в арсинале или знает как ее сделать, так как я в этом ноль.
Суть, есть база городов.

```
Пример:
Владивосток-Артем=30
Владивосток-Де-Фриз=10
Артем-Де-фриз=15
Штыково-Де-Фриз=40
Артем-Штыково=50
Штыково-Шкотово=20
```

Мы должны вписать: Владивосток-Шкотово. И исходя из этого нам должен построится кроткий маршрут.
Вывод выглядит следующим образом: Владивосток->Де-фриз->Штыково->Шкотово = 70км
Базу городов заполнять нужно в программе самой, а в консоле только вписываем откуда куда.

Comment: Так вам рассказать, какой алгоритм использовать для раоты с графом, или вы рассчитываете, что кто-то сделает все полностью за вас?

Comment: Да найдите любую реализацию задачи Коммивояжера и будет вам счастье

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что помочь - не значит сделать за вас...

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен Алгоритм Дейкстры [раз](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/dijkstra), [два](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B), [три](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/blogs/posts/21), [четыре](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-using-priority_queue-stl/)

Comment: Подозреваю, что автора вопроса интересует совсем не это. Судя по тому, что он на мой вопрос не ответил :)

Comment: Как раз "четыре" это то, что он хочет. Там добавить только вывод пути.